# Root element name in collections returned by RESTEasy

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using JAX-RS via RestEasy in JBoss AS 6. When my JAX-RS resource returns a collection of items (e.g. via a List), RESTEasy always uses the name `collection` as the root element.

E.g.

```
<collection>    
   <item>
     <description>computer</description>
     <price>2500</price>
   </item>

   <item>
     <description>tv</description>
     <price>1500</price>
   </item>
</collection>
```

This XML is generated by e.g.:

```
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("xml")
@RequestScoped
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("myitems")
    public List<Item> getMyItems() {
        return ...
    }
}
```

As can be seen the root tag that has been created by RESTEasy is always `<collection>`.

Jersey on the other hand always creates a name that is the plural form of the element contained in the list:

```
<items>    
   <item>
     <description>computer</description>
     <price>2500</price>
   </item>

   <item>
     <description>tv</description>
     <price>1500</price>
   </item>
</items>
```

I know it's possible to create a wrapper type and return that instead of a List, but that's a rather elaborate workaround and makes the code more complicated.

Is it possible to easily specify what the name of the root tag is for collections?

Comment: Slightly related, although from a JAXB perspective: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827788/how-do-i-marshal-java-util-list-with-jaxb-like-jax-rs-cxf-and-jersey-do

Answer (score 9):

Appeared to be a case of RTFM: [RestEasy docs - Arrays and Collections of JAXB Objects](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#JAXB_Collections)

> So, if we wanted to output this XML
>
> ```
> <foo:list xmlns:foo="http://foo.org">
>     <customer><name>bill</name></customer>
>     <customer><name>monica</name></customer>
> </foo:list>
> ```
>
> We would use the @Wrapped annotation
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> @GET
> @Path("list")
> @Produces("application/xml")
> @Wrapped(element="list", namespace="http://foo.org", prefix="foo")
> public List<Customer> getCustomerSet() { ... }
> ```

It's thus possible via the **@Wrapped** annotation. It's a RESTEasy specific one, but this will do for now.

Leaving the question open in case someone has an even better solution (still looking for a global interceptor orso that lets RESTEasy do what Jersey does).

Comment: Think about what that better solution would look like, and then try to get it included in the next version of the JAX-RS spec?

Comment: Probably some global adaptor just like the ones you can register for custom type conversion would be better.