# JAXB: How to add a Wrapper around XmlRootElement?

Tags: xml, collections, jaxb, jaxb2

How can I annotate a Bean for JAXB if I want to use such an XML file?

```
<myobjects>
    <myobject id="1" active="true">
        <...>
    </myobject>
    <myobject id="2" active="true">
        <...>
    </myobject>
    ...
    <myobject id="666666" active="true">
        <...>
    </myobject>
</myobjects>
```

...a list/collection of *XmlRootElements* is to be mapped to...

```
@XmlRootElement(name="myobject")
    public class XmlMyObjectDTO {
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle this use case.

### Option 1 - Introduce a New Top Level Class

You could introduce a new class called `XmlMyObjectDTOs` that contains a list of `MyXmlObjectDTO` objects.  Alternatively you could write a generic wrapper class (see link to related answer below):

- [Is it possible to programmatically configure JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272288/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-configure-jaxb/13273022#13273022)

### Option 2 - Use JAXB with StAX

You can create an `XMLStreamWriter` to write out the root element and then marshal the collection of objects to the `XMLStreamWriter`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: What would be the most convenient method?

Comment: @user233552 - Introducing the top level class is the easiest way.