# How to marshal list of objects with JAXB?

Tags: jaxb

How do I marshal a list of JAXB annotated objects without creating another class whose sole purpose is to be a container for the annotated objects?

Say I have this list:

```
List<MyObj> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

`List` is a great container for objects, how can I marshal `myList`?  I'm looking for an example that takes about 4 lines of code (about how much it takes to marshal a single `MyObj` instance) without creating any special helper classes.

I would accept an answer that had a generic helper class that could hold an arbitrary object type, like the `List` interface or the `ArrayList` class.  That way I could reuse the helper class for all my applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to programmatically configure JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272288/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-configure-jaxb)

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate of that question, though I think the question title here is a bit more clear :-)

Comment: I agree your title is better.