# Collection<?> wrap elements in plural name of actual type in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have a `Response` class which contains some basic attributes and a wildcard `Collection<?>`.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {
    private String approved;
    private String errorCode;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private Collection<?> collection;

    public Response() {
    }

    public Response(String approved, Collection<?> collection) {
        this.approved = approved;
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    public String getApproved() {
        return approved;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public Collection<?> getCollection() {
        return collection;
    }
}
```

This collection can contain many types, for example this type:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Transaction {
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String transactionId;

    public Transaction(BigDecimal amount, String transactionId ) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.transactionId = transactionId ;
    }

    public Transaction() {
        super();
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }
}
```

When serializing the `Response` class, I get this XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <approved>00</approved>
   <errorCode></errorCode>
   <transaction>
      <amount>500.00</amount>
      <transactionId>pgka3902</transactionId>
   </transaction>
   <transaction>
      <amount>201.05</amount>
      <transactionId>abcd3020</transactionId>
   </transaction>
</response>
```

Adding `@XmlElementWrapper` wraps `<transaction>` elements in `<collection>` which is not acceptable still. **I need the wrapper to be named the plural of the actual type in collection**. For example, the above xml should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <approved>00</approved>
   <errorCode />
   <transactions>
      <transaction>
         <amount>500.00</amount>
         <transactionId>pgka3902</transactionId>
      </transaction>
      <transaction>
         <amount>201.05</amount>
         <transactionId>abcd3020</transactionId>
      </transaction>
   </transactions>
</response>
```

Is it possible to do this with JAXB? I'm using Eclipselink Moxy implementation.

Comment: This seems relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/13273022/4074715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Response` holding a `Collection` you could change that to `Object`.  Then you could have different classes for each of your collection types.

```
 @XmlRootElement
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class Transactions {

     @XmlElement(name="transaction")
     private List<Transaction> transactions;

 }
```

Comment: This simple idea makes sense. Will try that, thanks Blaise :)

Answer (score 0):

The `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation has an optional parameter: `name`. If not specified, by default it will be the name of the Java field which is `collection` in your case. That's why your wrapper tag is named `<collection>`.

You can specify the name of the wrapper element/tag by passing the `name` argument to the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation like this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="transactions")
```

This will result in your desired XML tags.

Comment: Thanks, but you missed my point. This should be dynamic, depending on actual type in Collection<?>.

Comment: @isah I don't think that's possible. If it would be, JAXB would not be able to unmarshal an XML generated like this. Also a collection might contain elements of different types, how would you name the element then?

Comment: Actually it looks possible to me. I can use generics or bounded wildards which can contain specific types. Something similar is done here: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html

Comment: @isah Yes, but about unmarshaling, I was referring to this: what if your class has a field named `transactions`, it will end up in `<transactions>`. And now if your `collection` field contains `Transaction`s, by this rule it will also end up  using the element `<transactions>`. Now JAXB will have trouble unmarsaling this.