# How would I marshal a List of Jaxb Elements without making a wrapper class?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Short of actually making up a writer and appending each element onto the string. Is there a way to get the JAXB marshaller to marshall a list of objects where I can just give it the name of the top element?

I feel like I'm close with this

```
//http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html
public <T> String jaxb(Collection<T> o, Class<T> clazz, String plural){
    try {
        ArrayList<T> al = new ArrayList<T>(o.size());
        al.addAll(o);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ArrayList.class);
        JAXBElement<ArrayList> amenity = new JAXBElement(new QName(plural), ArrayList.class, al);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(amenity, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

but the result is still coming back as an empty list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pluralName/>
```

Is there a way to do this without just manually pasting strings of xml together?

### Update

With some help from Michael Glavassevich I've been able to do this with one caveat, the individual elements are `<Item>`s

```
//http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public <T> String jaxb(Collection<T> elements, Class<T> elementClass, String plural){
    try {
        T[] array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(elementClass, elements.size());
        elements.toArray(array);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(array.getClass());
        JAXBElement<T[]> topElement = new JAXBElement(new QName(plural), array.getClass(), array);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(topElement, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The result then becomes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Basketballs>
    <item>basketball one</item>
    <item>basketball two</item>
</Basketballs>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to create a wrapper class you could convert the collection into an array, place that array in a `JAXBElement` and then marshal it.

For example:

```
public class JAXBArrayWriter {

    public static class Item {
        @XmlValue
        protected String value;

        public Item() {}

        public Item(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Item("one"));
        items.add(new Item("two"));
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item[].class);
        JAXBElement<Item[]> root = new JAXBElement<Item[]>(new QName("items"), 
                Item[].class, items.toArray(new Item[items.size()]));
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(root, writer);
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }
}
```

which produces the following document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items>
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
</items>
```

Comment: This is step in the right direction, I'm having some trouble with one part though. Do you know how I would pass the class in to `JAXBContext.newInstance()` if I don't know the type? I apparently can't do `JAXBContext.newInstance(T[].class)`

Comment: actually never mind that i figured it out. I do have another problem though. If I change the Item class name to something like Basketball in your demo. The individual elements still come out as `<item>`. Any idea how to change this?

Comment: Seems to be related to the mapping rules for multidimensional arrays, equivalent to a schema type with `<xs:element name="item" type=schematype minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>`. At least at the spec level this isn't configurable.

Comment: What are the changes needed in above method to generate JSON instead of XML

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

First, create a list class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AmenityList {
    @XmlElement(name = "amenity")
    List<Amenity> amenities = new ArrayList<Amenity>();

    public AmenityList() {}

    public void setList(List<Amenity> amenities) {
        this.amenities = amenities;
    }
}
```

then the Amenity class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Amenity {
    private String amenityName;
    private String amenityDate;

    public Amenity(String name, String date) {
        this.amenityName = name;
        this.amenityDate = date;
    }
}
```

set where needed your amenities in a list - maybe in a less redundant way :) - and assign it to an AmenityList:

```
AmenityList amenityList = new AmenityList();
List <Amenity> amenities = new ArrayList<Amenity>();
amenities.add(new Amenity("a_one", "today"));
amenities.add(new Amenity("a_two", "tomorrow"));
amenity.setList(amenities);
```

and finally, a toXml method:

```
public static String toXml(AmenityList amenityList) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AmenityList.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(amenityList, sw);
    return sw.toString()
}
```

obtaining, i.e. :

```
<amenityList>
    <amenity>
        <amenityName>a_one</amenityName>
        <amenityDate>today</amenityDate>
    </amenity>
    <amenity>
        <amenityName>a_two</amenityName>
        <amenityDate>tomorrow</amenityDate>
    </amenity>
</amenityList>
```

Comment: I don't know that the list of objects will be amenities, which is why I'm trying to to do it without a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

POJO class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "classNameTAG")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ClassName {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="listTAG")
    @XmlElement(name="itemTAG") 
    private List<ClassItem> items;
}
```

The marshall code:

```
public static void pojo2xml(ClassName classData, File outputFile) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassName.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    m.marshal(classData, writer);
    writer.close();
}
```

Xml result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<classNameTAG>
    <listTAG>
        <itemTAG>data</itemTAG>
        <itemTAG>data</itemTAG>
    </listTAG>
</classNameTAG>
```

It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted solution with array works but causes each inner element to be named : < item >

The following solution taken from this link worked better for me:

[Is it possible to programmatically configure JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272288/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-configure-jaxb)

```
public class Wrapper<T> {

private List<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();

@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
public List<T> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

}

```
//JAXBContext is thread safe and so create it in constructor or 
//setter or wherever:
... 
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Wrapper.class, clazz);
... 

public String marshal(List<T> things, Class clazz) {

  //configure JAXB and marshaller     
  Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
  m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

  //Create wrapper based on generic list of objects
  Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>(things);
  JAXBElement<Wrapper> wrapperJAXBElement = new JAXBElement<Wrapper>(new QName(clazz.getSimpleName().toLowerCase()+"s"), Wrapper.class, wrapper);

  StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
  //marshal!
  m.marshal(wrapperJAXBElement, result);

  return result.toString();

}
```

It does not require converting the list to an array, but does require 1 generic general purpose class.