# How to marshal JAXBElement into Response?

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, cxf

My `CXF` provided `REST` services usually return `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` for the usual reason, to encapsulate the result entity data marshaled as XML and a return code:

```
@GET
@Path("/getPojo")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response getPojo() {

    SomePojo resultObj = ...;

    Response result = Response.status(200).entity(resultObj).build();

    return result;
}
```

which requires that `SomePojo` contains proper annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "somePojo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SomePojo implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

However, now I am facing a scenario where the annotation convention does not work for me and I have to build my own `JAXBElement`. How can I include the custom-marshaled JAXBElement in the `Response` instead of using `Response.ResponseBuilder.entity(resultObj)`, which relies on the annotation configuration? I am marshaling something similar to what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272288/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-configure-jaxb/13273022#13273022) but he's just printing the marshaled XML into the console and I would like to print it into the Response (and not just `HttpResponse` out).

Comment: Do you want to marshall yourself and return directly the XML, or do you want to configure CXF to apply a custom marshaller your result objects?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question but my gut feeling is to go with the former, marshal myself BUT I still would like to use `Response` because I want to encapsulate both a return code + object

Answer (score 1):

You can marshall the xml using your custom marshaller and set the resultant XML in the entity of the `Response`,  as `String` or `InputStream`

```
@GET
@Path("/getXML")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response getXML() {

    String xml = // custom marshall

    Response result = Response.
           status(200).
           entity(xml).
           type("application/xml").
           build();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: why is `type(application/xml")` necessary when we declare it in the annotation ?

Comment: You are building directly the response, not the CFX Response wrapper, so I am not sure whether in this case CXF will update the header properly. To be sure i would have to review the specification ( or test it)

Comment: Reviewed. In this case it is not needed  _A method for which there is a single-valued Produces is not required to set the media type of representations that it produces: the container will use the value of the Produces when sending a response._ see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html